# Upgrading to 2.81 - How To Keep Settings and Addons

Tags: customization

I currently have 2.8 and about to take a class that wants me to have 2.81.  I have invested time and money on my settings and some addons that I have purchased in the past.  I have done so much to the current blender that I have that Its hard to remember it all.

I currently have Blender 2.8 on my C drive and want to place Blender 2.81 on my D drive to save space.  Will I lose all of my settings and addons when I download the other version (2.81)?

Comment: I have two versions of Blender on my PC. I have kept 2.79b. Only I have changed the folder name and same inside, before downloading the latest 2.81. There, I have never lost 2.79b nor the addons. I keep all my addons in spare folders or external hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install 2.81, there is an option to import settings from 2.80. However it is unknown what custom tweaks you did to 2.80, so hard to answer if all will be that easy to transfer.

Under `<user>/AppData/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender` you'll find config files for all the version.

You won't loose addons, you will just have to copy them from 2.80 addon folder into 2.81 addon folder. Most addons will be fine, but some addons might not work under 2.81 and you'll have to wait until the addon developer updates the addon for 2.81. There are some small python API changes between 2.80 and 2.81.

Comment: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.81/Python_API