# How to properly update Blender?

Tags: interface

I want to update Blender, but I want to preserve all my old user settings etc. Should I just install the new version over the old folder (like the exact folder, in my case "Blender 2.93"), is there some kinda trick to exporting your settings to a new version?

Sorry for the interface tag, I had to put in something and I'm not allowed to create a new tag without 300 reputation first (which is idiotic if you ask me. There are better spam prevention measures than gating every feature behind reputation.)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57073/transfer-settings-to-new-version-of-blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78/how-would-i-import-export-blenders-preferences https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159509/upgrading-to-2-81-how-to-keep-settings-and-addons https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/where-is-the-startup-file-stored

Comment: TLDR is that on the first opening splash screen when you run a new version for the first time, there is an option to import settings from a previous version on your PC (if it exists).

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thank you!